# Matching the value of a word in a list with the place value of another list

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to work out how I can compare a list of words against a string and report back the word number from list one when they match. I can easily get the unique list of words from a sentence - just removing duplicates, and with enumerate I can get a value for each word, so Mary had a little lamb becomes 1, Mary, 2, had, 3, a etc. But I cannot work out how to then search the original list again and replace each word with its number value (so it becomes 1 2 3 etc).

Any ideas greatly received!

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list.index(word)
```

will return the index of the item **word** within **my_list**.  You can start digging into the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for this info. I can see the logic for this and it should work, however I get: line 27, in  output=words.index(result) ValueError: ['word1', 'word2'] is not in list With the following code:

```
def remove_duplicates(words):
    output = []
    seen = set()
    for value in words:
        # If value has not been encountered yet,
        # ... add it to both list and set.
        if value not in seen:
            output.append(value)
            seen.add(value)
    return output

# Remove duplicates from this list.
sentence = input("Enter a sentence ")
words = sentence.split(' ')

result = remove_duplicates(words)
print(result)
```

Very confusing :(

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer on here:

positions = [ i+1 for i in range(len(result)) if each == result[i]]

Which works well.